# free memory as I iterate over a list

Tags: python, list, memory-management

I have a hypothetical question regarding the memory usage of lists in python. I have a long list `my_list` that consumes multiple gigabytes if it is loaded into memory. I want to loop over that list and use each element only once during the iteration, meaning I could delete them from the list after looping over them. While I am looping, I am storing something else in memory, meaning the memory I allocated for `my_list` is now needed for something else. Thus, ideally, I would like to delete the list elements and free the memory while I am looping over them.

I assume, in most cases, a generator would make the most sense here. I could dump my list to a csv file and then read it line by line in a for-loop. In that case, `my_list` would never be loaded into memory in the first place. However, let's assume for the sake of discussion I don't want to do that.

Is there a way of releasing the memory of a list as I loop over it? The following does NOT work:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> sys.getsizeof(my_list)
80
>>> my_list.pop()
>>> sys.getsizeof(my_list)
80
```

or

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> sys.getsizeof(my_list)
80
>>> del my_list[-1]
>>> sys.getsizeof(my_list)
80
```

even when `gc.collect()` is called explicitly.

The only way that I get to work is copying the array (which at the time of copying would require 2x the memory and thus is again a problem):

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> sys.getsizeof(my_list)
80
>>> my_list.pop()
>>> my_list_copy = my_list.copy()
>>> sys.getsizeof(my_list_copy)
72
```

The fact that I don't find information on this topic indicates to me that probably the approach is either impossible or bad practice. If it should not be done this way, what would be the best alternative? Loading from csv as a generator? Or are there even better ways of doing this?

EDIT:
as [@Scott Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535275/scott-hunter) pointed out, the garbage collector works for much larger lists:

```
>>> my_list = [1] * 10**9
>>> for i in range(10):
...     for j in range(10**8):
...         del my_list[-1]
...     gc.collect()
...     print(sys.getsizeof(my_list))
```

Prints the following:

```
8000000056
8000000056
8000000056
8000000056
8000000056
4500000088
4500000088
2531250112
1423828240
56
```

Comment: I think It is not good practice to modify the list currently you are iterating over

Comment: Do you get the same behavior with larger lists?  *Much* larger lists (where the effort of actually collecting garbage would make an appreciable difference)?

Comment: @ScottHunter indeed, it works for larger lists. Thanks for pointing that out. I posted some results as edit.

Comment: Python allocates and deletes memory in blocks that are likely far larger than a single list entry.

Comment: popping should work. The memory isn't released after every pop (just like it isn't allocated after every append) but quick experiments show that the size of the list gets steadily smaller. Looking at `[1,2,3]` isn't sufficiently informative.

Comment: is an explicit call to gc.collect() required or does that happen automatically?

Comment: popping should release memory without gc.collect()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of your assumptions here are incorrect.

1. First biggie is the assumption that you can delete items as you loop over them with a `for` loop. [You can't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) You *could* with a `while` loop of the form:

   ```
   while my_list:
       item=my_list.pop(0)
       process(item)
       # Each my_list[0] element ref_count-- each loop...
       # If the ref_count==0, item is garbage collected automatically
       # But this is very slow with a Python list. 
       # Use a collections.deque instead
   ```
2. The garbage collector in Python is virtually seamless and automatic. It is rare to ever have to call the garbage collector from your program with programs that are written in common programming patterns. I can't think of anytime that it was needed in my use.
3. To answer one of your questions, if you call `.pop` on a list, the object pop'ed off the list has it reference count decreased. If it reaches zero, that object if garbage collected automatically -- no need to call `gc.collect()`.
4. The main use of calling `gc.collect()` is to delete self referring items that may have confused the default garbage collector. (ie, `a = []; a.append(a); del a`. In this case, the ref count for `a` never reaches 0 and is not deleted. [Here](https://stackabuse.com/basics-of-memory-management-in-python/) is an example.)
5. Python (depending in implementation) allocates and frees memory in blocks far larger than individual objects that are usually used in lists. Each `.append` or `.pop` to/from a list either goes to shared heap or then to a new allocation or release. [See here.](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html)
6. If you try and do per item memory management -- unless each item is huge -- it will be far less efficient than Python's automatic memory management.
7. You state that you are reading a large list from a file and then using those items for something else. So long as the items are not mutated -- usually this does not result in a new copy of the item. It results in the reference count of each item being increased.
8. If you read a large list from a file, mutate each item and keep a copy, then indeed your memory use goes up. However, your first list is automatically deleted when it goes out of scope.

All these issues are moot if you process the file line-by-line or use a generator of some sort to do so.

Here is an example. Assume you want to take a *big* text file and 1) read every line; 2) change "_" to ":" in every line; 3) have a list with every line so processed.

Given this 1.3 GB, 100,000,000 line file:

```
# Create the file with awk
% awk -v cnt=100000000 'BEGIN{ for (i=1; i<=cnt; i++) print "Line_" i }' >file

% ls -lh file
-rw-r--r--  1 dawg  wheel   1.3G Nov 14 12:34 file
% printf "%s\n...\n%s\n" $(head -n 1 file) $(tail -n 1 file)
Line_1
...
Line_100000000
```

You can process that file several different ways.

First is as you as thinking about:

```
from collections import deque 
# If you don't use a deque, this is too SLOW with a Python list

def process(dq):
    rtr=deque()
    while dq:
        line=dq.popleft()
        line=line.rstrip().replace("_", ":")
        rtr.append(line)
        
    return rtr    
        

with open('/tmp/file') as f:
    dq=deque(f.readlines())
    new_dq=process(dq)
    
print(new_dq[-1])
```

The second is with a line by line generator:

```
def process(line):
    return line.rstrip().replace("_", ":")

with open('/tmp/file') as f:
    new_li=list(process(line) for line in f)
    
print(new_li[-1])
```

The second method is a) Faster; b) less memory and c) easier and more Pythonic to write.

Don't overthink trying to manage memory. Python is a lot easier than C.

Comment: Nit: the garbage collector is used to break reference cycles, for example two objects that reference each other but not by any other object. Each will have a reference count of 1 but not reachable from any other part of the program, preventing either reference from being deleted.

Comment: @chepner: Agreed. Isn't that covered in #4?

Comment: Nesting doesn't imply a cycle, only that an object contains a reference to another object. If the object is nested in *itself*, we need the garbage collector. Compare `a = ["foo"]`, where `del a` will cause `"foo"`'s reference count (ignoring interning) to drop to 0 as well, with `a = []; a.append(a)`, where `del a` reduces the list's reference count to 1, but that reference only exists inside the list itself.  That list will lie around using space that can't reclaimed until the garbage collector finds and disposes of it.

Comment: I think you meant "moot" instead of "mute", although "mute" almost works...